# count data and Poisson GLMs to predict monetary amounts

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, poisson-regression

I have to predict money amounts, which are always greater than 0. The distribution is very tailed (i.e. there are many small values but also many large data).

Just wondering would a count data model (e.g. GLM + Poisson) be suitable for this kind of scenario?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

1. you shouldn't expect to get different results by changing from dollars to cents or from working in thousands to working in millions - but that's what happens if you use a Poisson model.
2. With money amounts you would generally expect spread to be proportional to mean rather than its square root (this would apply also to quasi-Poisson models). Indeed if one considers the effect of changes in inflation/interest under a Poisson or quasi-Poisson model (even if it's just constant either side of one change), we're left with inconsistent assumptions about variance.

Among GLMs "spread proportional to mean" would tend to suggest a gamma model.